# When is this map $ \pi : \left\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\right\} \to \left\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\right\}$ a permutation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, permutations

I'm trying to figure out this problem, with which I could use some help:

**Problem:** Under what conditions is the map $$ \pi : \left\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\right\} \to \left\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\right\}: i \mapsto (ai +b) \bmod n $$ a permutation ($a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$) ?

**Attempt:** For $\pi$ to be a permutation, it must be bijective. So first I was trying to figure out under what conditions it is injective. I let $i, j \in \left\{1, \ldots, n-1\right\}$, and I suppose that $i \neq j$. When is $\pi(i) \neq \pi(j)$? I think when $(ai) \bmod n \neq (aj) \bmod n$, or when $$ i \neq j + qn \qquad (q \in \mathbb{Z}) $$ that is, when $i$ is not some multiple of $j$ in terms of $n$.

For surjectivity, I let $j \in \left\{1, \ldots, n-1\right\}$. I need to find an $i \in \left\{1, \ldots, n-1\right\}$ such that $$ \pi(i) = (ai + b) \bmod n = j. $$ I'm not sure how to fulfill this condition.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: An injective map between finite sets of the same size is automatically surjective.

Comment: **Hint**: Split the problem in two smaller ones: $i \mapsto ai$ and $i \mapsto i+b$. Then your $\pi$ is just the composition of these two maps.

Comment: Is my proof on the injective part correct?

Comment: @Kamil If it is homework you should elaborate a little bit more why from $(ai) mod n \neq (aj) mod n$ follows $i  \neq j  qn$ for some $q \in \mathbb Z$.